# Disable a range of days in input date in Angular

Tags: html, angular, date, input, range

I have an Angular component where I have an input date, and I want to disable all the days on the past and at the same time a specific range of days in the future, for example the dates between 2023-10-15 and 2023-10-23. How can I do this? Is this possible? Thank you in advance.

I have tried something like this:

```
<input type="date" appDateRange>
```

Where appDateRange is a directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: '[appDateRange]'})export class DateRangeDirective {constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

@HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInput(event: Event): void {const inputElement = this.el.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;const selectedDate = inputElement.value;const currentDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];

// Define las fechas de inicio y fin del rango
const startDate = '2023-10-15';
const endDate = '2023-10-23';

if (selectedDate < currentDate || (selectedDate >= startDate && selectedDate <= endDate)) {
  inputElement.value = '';
}

}}
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can block specific dates with a "min" and "max" value :

```
<input name="yourdate" type="date" min="2023-03-03" max="2023-06-06">
```

And specific for angular :

```
 <input name="yourdate" type="date" min="{{startDate}}" max="{{endDate}}">
```

Comment: Yes, but how about the past days? I also want to disable it

Comment: The min value sets at which date you can start. So all days before this date can´t be selected

Comment: So is not possible to set different date ranges?